# How to connect to a socket server on the host machine via the virtual machine?

Tags: python, sockets, virtual-machine, port, portforwarding

I did the port forwarding: I put the server on the virutal machine, and connected the client from the host to the virtual machine. That worked well.

But now, when I tried to do this in the reverse direction, it did not.

First thing I did is a port forwarding with the following parameters:

- host port: 35001
- port to forward: 35001
- virtual machine ip: 192.168.40.130

It was done succesfully.

After that, when I did this (server script but on cmd (shell) on host):

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET , socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("0.0.0.0",35001))
```

I get this error:

```
  Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
```

I believe that is because there is a process listening on the port 35001.

It is VMware(NAT) listening on 35001, after I forwarded the port (I find that out using netstat).

So how to make a server on the host, make it listening to port 35001, and be able to connect to it from a virtual machine?

It is windows 10 pro, python3, a windows 7 VM. Firewalls are disabled. I don't want to use a bridged connection.

Answer (score 0):

The Vmware portforwarding is just a process, created by the vmware service, with the following parameters:

- it runs on your host machine
- allocates the TCP port 35001
- listens to incoming TCP connections
- forwards them to the TCP 35001 of your guest machine IP

This is what is does, and no more.

As your started the port forwarding, this process was started and allocated the 35001 TCP port on your host.

This is why your python script, on the host, did not work. It could not allocate the 35001 TCP port of your host again.

VMware creates a virtual network. Your virtual machines see this virtual network. No ethernet card belongs to it, but it looks as if it would. It has the 192.168.40.0-192.168.40.255 IP address range. Also your host machine is on this virtual network, probably with the IP 192.168.40.1. Your guest machine sees it as a router.

This is so for the host-only, bridged or NATted virtual network types. The virtual network types only affect, what your host machine does with the packets to forward them between the virtual and your physical network.

To run a server on your host, what you can connect from your guest, you do not need any port forwarding. Simply stop it, so your python script will run. Then, *connect 192.168.40.1:35001 from your guest*.